# Will I be punished for serial downvoting if I downvote a whole lot of wrong answers?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

In C and C++, arrays are not pointers. However, [many answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22arrays+are+pointers%22+is%3Aanswer) wrongly say that they are. Do I risk being punished for serial downvoting if I downvote all of those wrong answers?

Comment: Serial downvoting is on a *user*, not a *topic* so, unless it's the same user providing all of the bad answers, probably not. Except in exceptional circumstances, I believe the *"punishment"* is just automatic rollback of the votes, anyway.

Comment: @jonrsharpe should be an answer

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz just looking through the tag for dupes, I'll write it up if I can't find one.